# Combining LARGE, SUMPRODUCT, and logical filtering in Excel array function

Tags: excel, excel-formula

**Summary:** A complex (to me) multi-sheet array formula stops working in a certain column, and I can't figure out why.

**Setting:** I'm compiling a spreadsheet to establish values for fantasy baseball players. The Sheet1 contains the pasted raw statistics of every hitter, and Sheet2 contains intermediate computations that allow me to determine final values.

- In the example formulas, Sheet1 column C holds text strings designating position, and Sheet1 column E holds the number of at bats for each player.
- The third referenced column is associated with the statistic being processed.
- The first two formulas are working as intended, but I'm adding them to help contextualize the overall process.
- All three of these formulas are implemented on Sheet2.

**Formula A:** Intended to calculate a "replacement value" for a given statistic by averaging the 157th-171st values in the "qualified pool." Qualified values are values for which the player has at least 200 at bats. There are 12 teams times 13 hitters equals 156 league hitters.

`{=(SUMPRODUCT(LARGE(IF(Sheet1!$E$2:$E$1500 > 199, Sheet1!V$2:V$1500),ROW(INDIRECT("$157:$171"))))/15)}`

**Formula B:** Intended to calculate a "replacement value" for a given statistic for catchers only, due to scarcity at the position.  Works by averaging the 13th through 16th values in the "qualified pool" Qualified values are values for which the player has at least 200 at bats and the cell describing their position contains a "C". There are 12 teams times 1 required catchers equals 12 league catchers.

`{=(SUMPRODUCT(LARGE(IF((ISNUMBER(SEARCH("C",Sheet1!$C$2:$C$1500))) * (Sheet1!$E$2:$E$1500 > 199), Sheet1!V$2:V$1500),ROW(INDIRECT("$13:$16"))))/4)}`

**Formula C:** Intended to calculate a "replacement value" for a given statistic for non-catchers only. Works by averaging the 145th through 158th values in the "qualified pool." Qualified values are the inverse of formula B; the intent was to capture all values that don't contain a "C" in their position cell OR don't have at least 200 at bats.

`{=(SUMPRODUCT(LARGE(IF(((ISNUMBER(SEARCH("C",Sheet1!$C$2:$C$1500))) + (Sheet1!$E$2:$E$1500 < 200) > 0),, Sheet1!V$2:V$1500),ROW(INDIRECT("$145:$158"))))/14)}`

**Problem Behavior**: The formulas work perfectly with statistics pasted from an external source. However, four columns were added to Sheet1 whose values are derived from the pasted values. For example, Sheet1!V2 would hold the following formula:

`=$Q2-(Sheet2!$O$5 * $E2)`

Sheet2!O5 contains a formula based on values in Sheet1, but not the V column, only pasted values. The value of Sheet2!O5 is 0.4825.

**When applied to the four statistics that were added to Sheet1 and derived from pasted values, Formula C returns 0 for each one.**

Formulas A and B work with the four new statistics as expected, and Formula C works with all the pasted value statistics.

**Attempted Solutions:**

- Replacing the new calculated statistics with their values (instead of formulas)

**Misc:**

- The reason for using `IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH()))` is because some players may have multiple positions. I want to isolate everyone with a "C", even if there are more characters in the cell.
- One difference between the expected values for the four new statistics and the expected values for the pasted statistics is that the results that I'm expecting (that are returning zeroes) are expected to be *negative*. No other statistic to which Formula C is applied expects or returns negative values. However, Formula A and B return the negative values expected from the four new statistics without a problem.

**Question:** Why would this formula return a 0 from the newly added statistics, and what can I do or test to fix this problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know the reason, but the problem was fixed by adding the quotation marks to fill in the "value if true" part of the formula instead of putting the two commas next to each other.

The corrected formula:

`{=(SUMPRODUCT(LARGE(IF(((ISNUMBER(SEARCH("C",Sheet1!$C$2:$C$1500))) + (Sheet1!$E$2:$E$1500 < 200) > 0),"", Sheet1!V$2:V$1500),ROW(INDIRECT("$145:$158"))))/14)}`

Adding the quotation marks had no effect on the values of the columns where the data was positive, but switched the columns where the data was negative from 0 to the expected negative value.